# Check all possible labels (y) of an array or Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset with 12k samples, which each sample has one label y. How can I extract all possible outputs from these 12k samples? (the outputs can vary from 50 to 60 different values... I don't know).

Is there a built-in function for this? A way different than using a for on all samples like 60 times.... I don't know you but this loss of processment triggers me upset and makes the code so ugly.

Note: I don't want a list with the y of each sample, I just want to know how much y I have so I can set the 'number of outputs' of my learning model.

I solved it with:

```
    notfound = 0
    n_outputs = 0
    for num in range(1,80):
        temp = n_outputs
        try:
            for i in range(len(y)):
                if int(y[i]) == num:
                    n_outputs += 1
                    raise StopIteration

        except StopIteration:
            pass
        if temp == n_outputs:
            notfound += 1
        if notfound == 3:
            break

    print(n_outputs)
```

But is there another way?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html

Comment: `unique_values = numpy.unique(y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in the form of arrays, convert it into a pandas dataframe first and then do `data['output'].unique()`. It will give you a list of unique outputs. `data['output'].nunique()` gives you the number of unique values in your output column. `data` is your dataframe and `output` is your label column.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that my dataset doesn't has the output 0, but has 1..2...3.. etc. Do you think this will become a problem at the model?

Comment: @denisb415: No, the unique() function just returns the unique values in the column specified. It doesn't matter which values those are. This should still work for your problem. If this is what you are looking for, please accept the answer.